# Android: ProgressDialog and Show Data from XML Parsing Problem

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am parsing an XML from a URL and showing it. I want to show ProgressDialog while my XML Parser Method parse the XML and get it ready to show. The problem I am facing is that no data is shown after ProgressDialog rather it shows blank screen.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<XMLItem> items= new ArrayList<XMLItem>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mydata);
    adapter= new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.customcell, items);
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(id.ListView01);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            doTheAutoRefresh();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {
                    if(dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this line throws an exception and if i comment this line, blank screen is shown

                }

            });
        }

        });
        thread.start(); 
}

private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            loadData(); // this is where you put your refresh code
            doTheAutoRefresh();
             }
         }, 15000);

}

private void loadData(){
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = XMLReader.parseURL("my url to parse xml");



    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("l");



    for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++){

        NamedNodeMap np = nl.item(i).getAttributes();

        String t= np.getNamedItem("htn").getNodeValue();
        String sT= np.getNamedItem("atn").getNodeValue();
        XMLItem item= new XMLItem(t, sT);
        items.add(item);

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code shows ProgressDialog perfectly, but after progress dialog, it shows blank screen. Please help me sorting out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: what are you want to do after closing progress dialog just out that code on UI thread. after dialog.dismiss(); its adapter's notifyDatasetChanged() for your adapter.  I think you may want to use AsyncTask for this purpose. try it.

Comment: When do you add the items to the adapter?

Comment: after the completion of loaddata you have to setAdapter ..

Comment: did you populate the adapter?

Comment: @Sherif adapter is a class object I've written myself. This class extends `ArrayAdapter<XMLItem>`

Comment: @KasperMoerch yeah I've added items to adapter. I've edited my code now, please see now

Comment: yes but you are not populating your `adapter` ... If you are really populating it... try to use finally `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();`

Comment: @YashwanthKumar yeah I've populated the adapter

Comment: @Sherif I am populating it, I've edited my post. Please see now. If I've remove ProgressDialog code, then data is shown perfectly. So, no doubt about populating adapter

Comment: you have set adapter and then changing data, so use notifydatasetchanged() one you populate the data.

Comment: try to use adapter.notifydatasetchanged() on runonUIThread after   dialog.dismiss(); see what happen?

Comment: @YashwanthKumar I've added adapter.notifydatasetchanged() after dialog.dismiss(). It shows data perfectly. But I need to update my UI after each 15 seconds. I wrote a method doTheAutoRefresh() and calling it in Thread. Now, adapter.notifydatasetchanged() causes an exception and force close of my application and if i comment it, blank screen is shown

Comment: @user370305 I did, it works perfectly. But I need to update my UI after each 15 seconds. I wrote a method doTheAutoRefresh() and calling it in Thread. Now, adapter.notifydatasetchanged() causes an exception and force close of my application and if i comment it, blank screen is shown

Comment: I've edited my post. Please see for code.

Comment: you should use some handler for the task complete, the ways you are doing is quite complicated and may be wrong.

Comment: @YashwanthKumar can you please guide me a little what do mean actually? how to achieve what you are saying?

Comment: asyncTask is easy to use ,it will handle all the thread executions for you. you just have to use handler.postDelayed, in that case

Comment: @YashwanthKumar you mean all ProgressDialog plus loadData() methods in asyncTask? I am new to Android. Can you please refer me some link or code example to achieve this?

Comment: check my answer, it will give you an idea , how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(tranning.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();  
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // do your load data function part here.
        // just populate the data structures that are necessary 
        // for the adapter.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
          this.dialog.dismiss();
          // notify adapter here.
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          refreshTimer(); // to do the same thing after 15 seconds.
        }   
    }
}
```

now call the asycTask for the first time in your onCreate() probably.

```
new xyz().execute()
```

make a function to put a timer for refresh, we do that by using postDelayed.

```
private void refreshTimer(){
       handler.postDelayed( runner , 15000);
}

private Runnable runner  = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
               new xyz().execute();
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. Hat Offs for you... marked as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

**i think you need to implement AsyncTask ::**

```
private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(tranning.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();
        // put your code which preload with processDialog  
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // put your code here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
          this.dialog.dismiss();

        }   
    }
}
```

**and use this in main  ::**

```
new xyz().execute();
```

Comment: You should use this - but be aware that all changes to the content of a ListAdapter must be done on the UI-thread meaning during onPreExecute, onPostExecute or onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

add a function `showData()` and call it after dismissing the dialog

```
ArrayList<XMLItem> items= new ArrayList<XMLItem>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mydata);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(id.ListView01);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            loadData();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {
                    if(dialog.isShowing()){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        showData(); //////////////////////////////////////
                    }

                }

            });
        }

        });
        thread.start(); 
}
private void showData(){
    adapter= new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.customcell, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private void loadData(){
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = XMLReader.parseURL("my url to parse xml");



    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("l");



    for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++){

        NamedNodeMap np = nl.item(i).getAttributes();

        String t= np.getNamedItem("htn").getNodeValue();
        String sT= np.getNamedItem("atn").getNodeValue();
        XMLItem item= new XMLItem(t, sT);
        items.add(item);

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did by notifydatasetchanged(). It works. But I need to update my UI after each 15 seconds. I wrote a method doTheAutoRefresh() and calling it in Thread. Now, adapter.notifydatasetchanged() causes an exception and force close of my application and if i comment it, blank screen is shown. I've edited my post. Please see for code.